# Chrome Developer Tools can't see javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

So I am having this really weird thing where my javascript doesn't show in my sources window. If I set a `debugger` in my js and then reload the page, it will break and I can see the javascript. The weird thing is that instead of the tab being labeled `MyJavascriptFile.js` it reads `[VM](62)` or some other number. I have tried reinstalling chrome and it didnt fix my problem. It didn't used to be like this, any ideas what is going on? Its just really annoying to have get to my javascript by adding debugger statements.

Comment: How is your _JavaScript_ being loaded into the page?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://localhost/ivplugin/statics?isDev=true"></script>

Comment: It seems like this happened about the time I started doing performance profiles and memory analysis. I only did that for a day and haven't done anything like it for at least a week. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour for files not hosted on `localhost` (i.e. served by domain name or IP)?

Comment: It looks like I can see the scripts on stackOverflow's page.

Answer (score 7):

I'm having this problem right now.  Must be a bug in Chrome.  All you have to do is load the console (f12) then reload the page whilst the console is loaded.  You can now see your code.

Answer (score 4):

> The weird thing is that instead of the tab being labeled MyJavascriptFile.js it reads VM or some other number.

This is because you are accessing your script through `localhost`, and therefore running into security policies. If you host your file at an IP or domain name, you'll be able to debug normally again.

Comment: Well how come I didn't used to have that problem and my coworkers dont have that problem either? It's the same code.